# Can't extend C drive

Tags: windows

I've used Minitool partition, EaseUs partition, AOMEI tool. I have 105 unallocated space which I got from deleting another drive. Whenever I try to extend C, the PC goes into boot mode and an error message appears. Your PC ran into a problem and shows the blue screen of death. What should I do?

Here is a screenshot of disk management:

[image: Disk Management]

First, I tried to shrink 100 GB from (E:) using disk management. But it was taking too long, so I cancelled it. Now in Minitool it's saying,"E: drive currently being used". There's also a move (E:) operation in the pending list. It's popping up on its own because I'm only trying to extend the unallocated space.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: Ok sir.........

Comment: Please use the upload function provided by [su] or Imgur itself. The image is currently not accessible.

Comment: Can you please try again. I forgot to check on the link sharing option.

Comment: Can’t access the image.  Upload the image using the functionality of this website (hit the button)

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  The bottom line is that you can only extend the `C:` partition into the unallocated space if it is adjacent to `C:`.  In other words, the unallocated space needs to appear just to the right of the `C:` partition within your Disk Management interface.

Comment: Before proceeding any further, you should verify that whatever is on `E:` is still okay. Canceling the shrink operation could have damaged the filesystem. Run `chkdsk`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy and simple. You can do this by booting from Acronis Disk Director LiveCD

https://archive.org/download/Acronis.Disk.Director.v12.0.Build.3270BootCD/Acronis.Disk.Director.v12.0.Build.3270-BootCD.iso

Manual there - https://www.acronis.com/en-us/download/docs/add12h/userguide/.

You must first move the "E" and "Healthy" (714MB) partitions to the right so that the free space is next to "C", and then expand "C" (`Resize partition`).

Answer (score 0):

If you still received the message"E: drive currently being used" after all files/programs are closed, probably the page file caused the issue. Just noticed both C: and E:are with the Page File feature. You can temporarily disable page file, then move the unallocated space to be after drive C: with minitool partition wizard, and then extend C: in Disk Management.